# Passing data to a custom layer in Keras

Tags: keras

I'm attempting to implement the `Differentiable Neural Dictionary` from this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01988 in Keras

I'm creating a custom layer to act as the DND, however I need to pass data to this layer every run, specifically the key and Q-value. Unfortunately I've been unable to so far, is there any way to pass these values to my custom layer through some kind of function call?

It seems as though once the layer is created and compiled I can't modify or append any information to its data structures, but any and all help is appreciated

Examples where the custom layer is `DNDLayer`

```
dnd = DNDLayer()(previous_layer)
...compile model etc...
dnd.method()
```

results in

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'method'
```

Since I'm assuming the object is converted into a tensor for the model. Declaring the layer separately and adding it to the model doesn't result in an error, but the actual data in the layer doesn't change, it seems to be static

Comment: What errors you get? Please add full stack trace and the minimal code to show where it is happening

Comment: Updated it with some more information. It seems as though the layer is converted into a tensor when the model is compiled, but I can't seem to find a way to pass outside information to it